# Server Error in / Application in asp.net (the same code is working fine in test server)

Tags: asp.net

I am getting the following error when i publish the website code.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

[No relevant source lines]

Source File: c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\dubs_test\4fc875e9\c05ca91a\App_Web_dataentry.aspx.cdcab7d2.v9c2efde.0.cs    Line: 0

Stack Trace:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]    DataEntry..ctor() +96    ASP.dataentry_aspx..ctor() in
>   c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\dubs_test\4fc875e9\c05ca91a\App_Web_dataentry.aspx.cdcab7d2.v9c2efde.0.cs:0
>   __ASP.FastObjectFactory_app_web_dataentry_aspx_cdcab7d2_v9c2efde.Create_ASP_dataentry_aspx()
>   in c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\dubs_test\4fc875e9\c05ca91a\App_Web_dataentry.aspx.cdcab7d2.v9c2efde.1.cs:0
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert) +146
>   System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context,
>   String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath) +62 
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String
>   requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean
>   useAppConfig) +573
>   System.Web.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +182    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +276

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is a problem with a path that you referencing. The paths that you provide may work on your local but not on server. Try to check your paths.
Also this will help you [ASP.NET Web Project Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

please make sure you have same database objects, configuration settings in both test and production server.

Comment: Yes we have the same database objects for test and production

Comment: If we are not missing anything, let's try this one. please delete you bin and obj folder. Also please delete the Temporary ASP.NET File folde for this location. c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files. Then clean up the solution and build the application.